# aiohttp - unable to serve requests asyncronously

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I am playing with `aiohttp` lib, trying to create a simple async handler that sleeps and then returns.

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp import web


async def handle(request):
    print('before sleep')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('   after sleep')
    return web.Response(text='')



app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([
    web.get('/', handle),
])

web.run_app(app)
```

Then I open the web server in several Chome tabs simultaneously.

The expected behaviour is random prints in the console, something like this:

```
before sleep
before sleep
before sleep
   after sleep
before sleep
   after sleep
   after sleep
   after sleep
```

however what I see in the console is perfectly synchronous execution, with my requests handled one by one:

```
before sleep
   after sleep
before sleep
   after sleep
before sleep
   after sleep
before sleep
   after sleep
```

what is wrong with my way of writing the handler?

Comment: where is the code getting run?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest on my local mac os